# How do I evaluate this complex integral without using Cauchy's Integral Formula or Residue Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am given a complex integral:
$\oint_c \frac{e^{iz}}{z(z-\pi)}dz$ where C is the boundary of the annulus between circles of radius 1 and radius 4. So we have singularities at $\ z=0$ and $\ z=\pi$

I know that this integral is equivalent to 
$\frac{1}{\pi}[\oint_c \frac{e^{iz}}{z-\pi}dz - \oint_c \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz$] using partial fraction decomposition.

I think I know how to solve the second integral $\oint_c \frac{e^{iz}}{z}dz$ by expanding out the numerator into infinite series sum and the singularity point in the denominator "cancels out" and the integral becomes much easier to solve using Cauchy-Goursat theorem.

However, I cannot for the life of me evaluate $\oint_c \frac{e^{iz}}{z-\pi}dz$. Even if I expand out the numerator $\ e^{iz}$ into

$\ 1+iz-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{iz^3}{6}+...$  ,

the singularity does not cancel out, so I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't the function you're integrating actually analytic on the annulus? (The singularities are outside.) So what does Cauchy's Theorem tell you the integral over the boundary of the annulus is?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant annulus between circles of radius 1 and radius 4. Wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks